# Ruby downcase method not working as expected

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

I am writing a small bit of code in Ruby that is supposed to redact a word that is specified by the user, regardless if the word that is being passed is all uppercase, lowercase or a combination of the two. The way that I tried to get around this was by just using the `downcase!` method on the strings being passed by the user. However, it would seem that it does not work correctly. For example, if the first string that is passed and stored in the variable "text" is in all uppercase and the second string that is passed and stored in the variable "redact" is all `downcase`, the program will fail to redact the word and will just print out everything in `downcase.`

Here is the code below:

```
puts "Enter what you want to search through"
text = gets.chomp.downcase!
puts "Enter word to be redacted"
redact = gets.chomp.downcase!

words = text.split(" ")

words.each do |word|
 if word == redact
     print "REDACTED "
 else
     print word + " "
 end
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you use `downcase!` which will return `nil` if no change is made. The string itself is modified but the returned value is `nil`, which you save after in your `text` variable.

See the documentation about [downcase](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-downcase) and [downcase!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-downcase-21) to understand the difference.

Answer (score 2):

```
puts "Enter what you want to search through"
text = gets.chomp.downcase
puts "Enter word to be redacted"
redact = gets.chomp.downcase

words = text.split(" ")

words.each do |word|
 if word == redact
     print "REDACTED "
 else
     print word + " "
 end
end
```

try it without the exclamation marks.